# How to disable or remove security method Windward?

Tags: windward

Using windward while convert doc to pdf . How to disable / remove security method, Please suggest me possible way to restrict security method.

Currently using  WindwardRestApi in .Net

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My guess is he's trying to get around the license check to avoid paying for the software.